# how to add my external jar file to class path

Tags: maven, apk

I am new to maven environment, need some ones help.
Added my external jar file (directoryhelper.jar) in lib folder as below in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.test.directoryhelper</groupId>
      <artifactId>DirectoryHelper</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <scope>system</scope>
      <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/directoryhelper.jar</systemPath>      
</dependency>
```

compilation is successful, but during run time I am getting 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.

how to add the directoryhelper.jar to class path.

Comment: How are you trying to run?

Comment: after building with mvn clean install, I install apk to phone, then try to access from browser.

Comment: Okay, no one said anything about APKs :) How about a tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maven out of the box will come up with a JAR file (default packaging). This JAR file only contains (`main`) artifacts of the project. If you take just that and run it, clearly the dependencies are missing -- by design.

Typically Maven artifacts are reused in combination with their POM so that at the point of use it's know what the dependencies are. Edit: if you're using APKs and installing them on a phone, there may be mechanisms to deal with dependencies, I'm answering this merely from a Maven standpoint.

If you want to create a JAR *with* dependencies you have to tell Maven to do so, that's not the default.
Ways of having Maven do that are (probably not exhaustive):

- [Maven Assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/), `jar-with-dependencies` predefined descriptor:

  ```
  <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
      <configuration>
          <descriptorRefs>
              <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
      </configuration>
  ...
  ```
- [Maven Shade plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I wrote simple application in eclipse by importing and come to know the jars dependencies and added  those dependencies to pom.xml, it solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

That way it'll create a single-jar of large size and build time will be large everytime you try to build.

I instead prefer adding all jars to a lib folder and including in the classpath (jar's manifest), because of which when we have to make some change or redeploy to the client or some place, we can simply give the small jar (not all the dependencies merged within jar)

```
          <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>com.kalindiinfotech.webcrawler.MainGUI</mainClass>
                            <!--                            <mainClass>com.KalindiInfotech.busbookingmaven.form.LoginForm</mainClass>-->
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: To get this working for me I had to include "-cp lib/*:fully.qualified.MainClassName.jar" to the java command to run the jar.